# Generate model classes from database using EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using EF Core 3.1 in a .NET Core 3.1 project. I am wondering if there is any way to generate or update model classes using Database first except having an .edmx file. The reason is that we have a SQL developer that is developing and maintaining the database and I was wondering if there is a way other then having .edmx file to reflect database changes into model classes. For example generating model classes from an existing visual studio database project.

Comment: Are you looking for scaffolding? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding?tabs=dotnet-core-cli - this will generate model classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the same purpose, we use [EF Core Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EFCorePowerTools) *Reverse Engineer* feature. It lets you use [handlebars templates](https://handlebarsjs.com/) for to-be-generated-entity-classes, so we can easily add custom `using` statements and inheritance from our base entity class. Hope it works for you as well.

Here is the link to the [built-in scaffolding feature](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding).